# Is there such a pattern in JS?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there a concise way to implement the following design pattern?

```
function a() {
    function x() { /* code */ }
    function y() { /* code */ }
    /* more code */
    x(); y(); // these can be called here
}

a();
a.x();
a.y();
```

I got acquainted with prototypes recently, and could probably use something like this:

```
a = function() { }
a.prototype.x = function() { }
a.prototype.y = function() { }
```

But maybe there's a slimmer way? Since in my code `a` also belongs to something else's prototype, i.e.

```
function plugin() { ... }
plugin.prototype.a = function () {}
plugin.prototype.a.prototype.x = function () {}
plugin.prototype.a.prototype.y = function () {}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `But since in my code a also belongs to something else's prototype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like that:

```
function a() {
    this.x = function () { /* code */ }
    this.y = function () { /* code */ }
    /* more code */
    this.x(); this.y(); // these can be called here
}

var test = new a();
test.x();
test.y();
```

Comment: Ah... this seems promising. I'm gonna go check if it works out for me.

Comment: This seems to be almost a duplicate of the code in your question. How did this address your question? What new approach is revealed? And I want to say it so this isn't misinterpreted: these are sincere questions; I'm trying to understand the difference between the 2 code blocks, because I feel like I am missing something. Thanx -

Comment: @SeanMickey look closer at `this` statement. I've make functions public.

Comment: @antyrat Oh right, I see now - and you call `a()` with `new`, so you construct an instance. I did miss it. And I thought the question went _much_ deeper than that. Thanks for the fast follow-up

Answer (score 1):

**Why dont use simply define function **a*** like this:*

```
function a( x , y){
   x();
   y();
}
```

**and Call it like this:**

```
x = function(){
 // some code
}

y = function(){
 // some code
}

a(x,y);
```

**OR for that matter like this**

```
a(
function(){
  // some code
},
function(){
 // some code
}

);
```

**Even If 'a' belongs to someone else's prototype**

You can do this :-

```
  someOtherObj.prototype.a = function( x , y){
       x();
       y();
     }
```

and while calling just pass x and y either after defining or anonymously.

Comment: Nope. Not what I need at all.

Comment: Then what do you want to treat a as ? class-object or a higher-order function ?

Comment: Well, I don't want to pass `x` and `y` to `a`. I want them to be declared inside `a`, but I also want to be able to call them from outside it.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the state of your code and avoid clash by using [singleton or module pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/):

```
var foo = function(){
  // private members
  var bar;
  baz: function(){return bar;}

  // public members go here
  return {
    getBaz: baz
  }
}();
```

Only members that you provide via `return` above are available to outside scope, rest remains within that object only.

For more design pattern ideas, see:

- [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for JavaScript language mechanisms that support dynamic object composition like what you describe in your question, there are three related functions of `Object` that may help (**note that all three require** [JavaScript 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8.5)):

- [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
- [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
- [Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

If you are looking more for an *actual Design Pattern*, there are many that touch on aspects of your question, but I believe the Design Patterns that best fit the building block approach that seems to be the primary theme of your question, are described in these articles (by different authors) about implementing Design Patterns in JavaScript:

- [Composite Pattern](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-design-patterns-composite/), from [Joe Zim's JavaScript Blog](http://www.joezimjs.com/)
- [Mixin Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mixinpatternjavascript), from the free online book: [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Hope this is helpful -